# How to customize a static code analysis, which was triggered by sonar cube?

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, sonarqube

is there a way to customize the metrics, which was used by analysing java code in a maven project? Or in other words: How can I customized the criteria, which are used, if Sonar cube analyse my java maven project?

Comment: There are lots of ways to customize the Sonarqube analysis. Either look at the online docs http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Documentation or be more specific about what you need to customize

Answer (score 0):

This is a post on my blog that shows how to customize a SonarQube Quality Profile http://qualilogy.com/en/plsql-analysis-sonarqube-plsql-quality-profile/

Hope it helps.